# Paperclip.Run and FFMPEG exit codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, paperclip

I'm writing a paperclip processor that class ffmpeg using the Paperclip.run command. Currently, that line throws an Cocaine::CommandLineError stating

> Command '/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i
>   "/tmp/stream20110729-2442-133evp0.mp3"
>   "/tmp/stream20110729-2442-133evp020110729-2442-15k6sr4.ogg"
>   2>/dev/null' returned 1. Expected 0

This doesn't really tell me a lot about what's going on, and I can't find anything about FFMPEG error code 1.

I need to find more information about what's happening in FFMPEG, but it seems the error output is being sent to /dev/null (something Paperclip adds to my command).

BTW I'm running RoR with Passenger on Apache 2 on OSX Snow Leopard.

**How can I get ffmpeg to log more details about the issue?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What was your issue? Please share your knowledge. I ran in the same problem and from what I can see under Rails 2.x it doesn't get the parameters I'm sending from the model so it just runs a basic command with no options passed through the convert_options. I wonder if you had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the option `:swallow_stderr => false` to the Paperclip.run call. It'll instruct the command line processor not to redirect the standard error to /dev/null and you might get the errors FFMPEG is generating.

Comment: Thanks eugen. Where would that log to, my apps Rails log or an OSX log of sorts?

Comment: If you are running under `rails server` they will appear on the console, otherwise in the web server error logs.

Comment: I'm running on apache / passenger, which does not use rails server. Is it possible to use this stack with rails server or do I need to be using mongrel? I'm not opposed to switching to the latter, it seems to me a more maintainable option (BTW I'm new to rails if you haven't guessed yet, thank you for your insite).

Answer (score 1):

You can try running this command manually to see what's happening. Is this your mp3-file?
Also, check if ffmpeg is actually installed where it tries to run it from(it can be in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`...).

Comment: I can't fully simulate the conditions ffmpeg runs under. Apache executes it, the source file is placed in the tmp directory with some level of security and ownership, etc. It would be more natural and future proof if I could turn on native logging for it. Thanks for your suggestion though