# ffmpeg php encoding trace encode failures

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am executing ffmpeg from php's **exec**

```
function convertToMP4($sourceFile,$outputfile)
{
    $Command="ffmpeg -i ".$sourceFile.".".$outputfile." 2>&1";
    exec($Command,$result,$status);
    return $result;

}
```

I am getting result of the entire command to an array

> $result.

**My question is ,how can I exactly find out if a video fails to encode.**

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate or related of [Paperclip.Run and FFMPEG exit codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878505/paperclip-run-and-ffmpeg-exit-codes)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) $status will contain the exit value of the process, and normally 0 means success, rest mean error.

```
function convertToMP4($sourceFile,$outputfile)
{
    $Command="ffmpeg -i ".$sourceFile.".".$outputfile." 2>&1";
    exec($Command, $result, $status);

    if($status !== 0) {
        echo "Error!";
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You convert errors to the result. But you hide the result in case of an error. Just seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function if you don't need the output. With the second argument you can get the return value of the command. In unix systems the `0` return value means success and anything else error.

```
system('/bin/false', $ret);
var_dump($ret);
```

The same can be achieved with exec's third parameter too.